# in jquery ui datepicker, on the OnSelect() event is there anyway to get the previous selected date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

i have code on the **onSelect** event of the [jquery ui datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) and i now want to only run my function if the date has changed values (so if a user selects a date that was already there in the textbox, i don't want to run this code as it will be a redundant calculation).  Here is my existing code.

```
$('#Milestone').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
    onSelect: calcUpdate
});
```

Comment: try the onchange event to fire a calculating function.

Comment: @Coding-Freak - i don't see an OnChange event here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: maybe use $('#Milestone').click() to get the date, then check that date against the date that was selected.

Comment: @Matt - i assume the #Milestone.Click event would always fire before the onSelect event of the datepicker . . is that something i can count on ?

Comment: Actually looks like there's a beforeShow event. Use that to get the date before anything is selected.

Comment: by the way, i was asking to add a onchange event to the DOM of the #milestone, not to the javascript datepicker function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use data to store previously stored value and compare the current value to it.

Try this(put these statements in your document ready event):

```
$('#Milestone').data("prev", $(this).val());
$('#Milestone').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText){
            var prevDate = $(this).data("prev")
            var curDate = dateText;
            if(prevDate == curDate){
              $(this).data("prev", curDate)
                calcUpdate();
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: does .data() work with every browser.  I thought that was just a html 5 thing??

Comment: @ooo: The `data-*` attribute on an HTML element is HTML5. Using the jQuery `data(...)` method will work on any browser.

Comment: Doesn't work properly: Just change twice the value of the date and you'll always get the onload value as "previous one". Reza Mamun answer is the right one: use the property of the datepicker object "lastVal" that is regularly updated per edit.

Answer (score 16):

According to http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect, you should try this:

```
$('#Milestone').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd M yy',
    onSelect: function(curDate, instance){
        if( curDate != instance.lastVal ){
            //so, the date is changed;
            //Do your works here...
        }
    }
});
```

The onSelect function receives 2 parameters which are used here;
You can debug/console the values of the 2nd parameter to know more about it.

Comment: @leora please accept this as the right answer, Chandu's one is buggy and doesn't fullfill OP request.

Comment: Unfortunately instance.lasVal is not updated while DatePicker is open.